# Libtool think that a "library was moved" but it isn't the case

Tags: gtk, libtool, freetype, pango, x86-64

I am currently recompiling gtk+ and dependencies from source (I have no other choices).

All my custom packages are installed in a specific custom point (let's call it `/packages`) (it can seem odd but this time again, I have no other choices).

When I try to recompile pango, it needs freetype.
Freetype is already installed in `/packages/freetype/2.1.10/amd64-linux`  (lib, include ... are in this directory) and the different config path are set (`LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `LIBRARY_PATH`, `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH`, `INCLUDE_PATH`, `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`).
configuration of pango run well. It find freetype and generate the Makefile.
When I try to make, I get the following error :

```
libtool: link: warning: library `/packages/freetype/2.1.10/amd64-linux//lib/libfreetype.la' was moved.
grep: /usr/local/lib/libfreetype.la: No such file or directory
```

libtool has a problem with my lib (but libfreetype.la exists in the directory `/packages/freetype/2.1.10/amd64-linux//lib/`and there's no problem of access). So libtool try to find it in the "classic places" like `/usr/...` and don't find it.

At the beginning, I thought that libtool get confused with the two slashes (probably due to an error in the --prefix flag during the compilation of freetype) so I did recompile freetype without the typo but it didn't change anything.

Has anybody an idea to help me ? I have never used libtool in my personnal projects before so I don't know if there's a way to solve this strange behavior... (It's maybe irrelevant but libtool is version 1.5.22)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have you looked inside the `libfreetype.la` file? Libtool `.la` files are just text files describing libraries. By default, they are commented. Search for the `libdir` and `dependency_libs` settings and check if they point to the right places.

Comment: Thank for your help ! By checking manually the .la files of all dependencies, I manage to solve the problem by replacing the occurences of /usr/local/lib/libfreetype.la by the right one. I didn't know that .la file where just "config" file for linking...